# Showing visual Data in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, responsive-design

Screen shot below, reads data from some database - I think I can get my head around reading data from DB with some RubyOnRails tutorial I am following -  but then how should I be able to represent that data in a pretty shape that they want like this picture below?

What tools, frameworks, etc. should I get myself familiar with very quick to be able to represent the data like this?

Since I am should focus on Rails, it would be great if what you suggest is in something that integrate well with Rails too...

[image]

Screen shot2:  for this one I "think" somehow I can use "Google Charts" but still good to have your suggestions too.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make charts you use javascript. There is a lot of libraries out there.

Those small charts in the first picture are called sparklelines. They can be made with this jquery plugin

[jQuery Sparklines](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about)

And this pure javascript tool

[sparklines.js](http://willarson.com/code/sparklines/sparklines.html)

For other charts I think the best free one is the [d3](http://d3js.org/) library and spesially the [nvd3](http://nvd3.org/) library witch is built on top of the d3 library.

There are also some solutions with the  [Raphaël—JavaScript Library](http://raphaeljs.com/). 
One is [gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/).
I personally do not like this one, but have a look.

Charting libraries often use SVG's (Scalable Vector Graphics. Go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Getting_Started/SVG_and_CSS) to learn about SVG and CSS ) to display the charts. And you feed the data from Rails trough JSON.

Rails can render JSON from the controllers and you can use [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) *"Jbuilder gives you a simple DSL for declaring JSON structures that beats massaging giant hash structures."*

I usually end up with a custom class in the lib directory, because charting usually requires a lot of complex queries and handling of data from the database before you can send it to the chart.

You should see these railscasts. [railscasts#223](http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts) [railscasts#223revised](http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts-graphs-revised)

The first uses highcharts (Not free) and the last use [morris.js](http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/). Morris is rather simple, but in some chases sufficient. 
The last one is the best, but I guess you have to get a subscription to see it.

There is a lot to learn here, and that is fun!

Comment: great great answer. Thanks.  So looks like I must also learn jQuery? but "how much" of jQuery do you think I need to know to keep me going with this project? I am kind of under deadlines to create this, so prefer to focus on the parts that I need to know . Thanks again.

Comment: You don't need jquery.  Added a simple sparkleline pure javascript library in the answer. But, if you know some javascript, jQuery is not very difficult. Rails is geared up to run with jquery, so I think this might be a god time to start learning. Start at [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=jquery)