# Is this the most 'Rails' way to do a dashboard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've build a management panel for a website I'm working on and it all works brilliant. Now there needs to be a front page that acts as a 'Dashboard.' It'll display different graphs representing various models and parts of the application over time. It'll also show smaller lists of various items (customers that need to be called etc.) I've got a dashboard working, but I'm just wondering if there's a better way of doing it in rails. I basically just have a dashboard controller:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @statistics = {}
    @statistics[:leads] = Lead.this_month.count
    @statistics[:leads_by_day] = Lead.date_count
    @statistics[:called_this_month] = Customer.called_this_month.count
  end
end
```

I don't want to use any gems, because this is going to require a tonne of configuration and it needs to look a certain way

Comment: I'd avoid hashes, they contain stuff and you're likely to want some clear info => use dedicated objects and/or presenters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can lead to a lot of code and conditions in the view layer and it might be hard to test.

**Extract all code**

You should extract all code to one or more classes. The advantages is that you can get really clean code with many one liner methods and you can test them in isolation from rails witch makes you test lightning fast. [Fast Rails Tests
by Corey Haines](http://www.confreaks.com/videos/641-gogaruco2011-fast-rails-tests)

**There are different opinions for how to do this.**

- Put these files into the lib directory and require them where needed.
- Make presenters

  There is a great
  [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch)
  about it ( it requires pro subscription )

Comment: Thank you! So a Dashboard Controller with a presenter (I haven't had time to look them up yet so excuse me if I'm misinterpreting what they are) would be the correct way to go?

Comment: Oh and: There's not any conditions in the view at all. Really just cycling over `[:leads_by_day]` and outputting the other two

Comment: Yeah dealing with graphs is kind of messy ;) I'm using a plugin for jquery however that just means you have one table and then a separate `td` for each point of data

Comment: If you're making charts and graphs take a look at my answer at this question.[Showing visual Data in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295458/showing-visual-data-in-ruby-on-rails/14297139#14297139). I am listing a few ways to make them. It might be of interest. Good look!

Comment: Thanks! I will do in future. Luckily for this project, it's only a small line graph that's needed. So I'm using this: https://github.com/em-/jquery-visualize